# VSCode terminal not displaying time correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting this problem with my VSCode terminal, where it doesn't show the time correctly, I am using powerlevel10k and it works fine on my regular terminal. I downloaded and installed the MesloLGS NF font that was recommended yet it still did not work. I have included two images, one is the iterm image and the other is the vscode terminal.
[image: Iterm2 termninal]

[image: VSCode terminal]

Answer (score 1):

you can change `Terminal > Integrated: Gpu Acceleration` to off

On/Auto (there should be `done` icon on the line end):

[done icon is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrfuH.png)

Off:

[done icon is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLhFd.png)